# Find searches only for the first matching entry

Tags: command-line, find, mount, search, file-server

I have to find all directory paths with specific subfolders.

The search pattern is as follows:

```
find /foo/*/searched_folder/bar -maxdepth 0 -type d
```

̶I̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶w̶o̶r̶k̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶p̶r̶e̶t̶t̶y̶ ̶w̶e̶l̶l̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶d̶ ̶i̶n̶ ̶v̶e̶r̶s̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶4̶.̶6̶,̶ ̶b̶u̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶v̶e̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶l̶s̶o̶ ̶o̶l̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶4̶.̶5̶.̶1̶2̶.̶ ̶A̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶'̶s̶ ̶w̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶b̶l̶e̶m̶s̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶r̶t̶.̶ ̶
̶
̶I̶n̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶o̶l̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶v̶e̶r̶s̶i̶o̶n̶,̶ ̶a̶f̶t̶e̶r̶ ̶f̶i̶n̶d̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶s̶t̶ ̶e̶n̶t̶r̶y̶,̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶p̶r̶o̶g̶r̶a̶m̶ ̶s̶t̶o̶p̶s̶ ̶s̶e̶a̶r̶c̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶n̶d̶ ̶r̶e̶t̶u̶r̶n̶s̶ ̶o̶n̶l̶y̶ ̶o̶n̶e̶ ̶e̶n̶t̶r̶y̶. I̶ ̶w̶a̶s̶ ̶t̶r̶y̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶u̶s̶e̶ ̶o̶p̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ `-prune` b̶u̶t̶ ̶w̶i̶t̶h̶o̶u̶t̶ ̶s̶u̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶.̶ ̶I̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶n̶y̶ ̶e̶x̶t̶r̶a̶ ̶a̶r̶g̶u̶m̶e̶n̶t̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶e̶a̶r̶c̶h̶ ̶t̶h̶o̶s̶e̶ ̶f̶o̶l̶d̶e̶r̶ ̶p̶a̶t̶h̶s̶,̶ ̶o̶r̶ ̶m̶a̶y̶b̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶ ̶o̶t̶h̶e̶r̶ ̶w̶a̶y̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶s̶e̶a̶r̶c̶h̶ ̶i̶t̶?̶
̶

I want find the directories that match the particular pattern, and integrate it into bash script as an path array. Everything is already working except search.

```
SORCE_ARRAY=($(find /projekte/*/$AB/software/software.git/ -maxdepth 0 -type d))
```

Real example

```
find /projekte/*/3140/software/software.git/ -maxdepth 0 -type d
```

New version (openSUSE Tumbleweed):

```
/projekte/ABBA/3140/software/software.git/
/projekte/JERRY/3140/software/software.git/
/projekte/LED/3140/software/software.git/
```

Older version (openSUSE Leap 15.1):

```
/projekte/ABBA/3140/software/software.git/
```

---

## Update

The problem are soft links.
The structure on Linux openSUSE Tumbleweed does not distinguish whether it is a soft link or a regular folder on server. I thought that 3 folders exist, and it turned out that the last two results are soft links.

Meanwhile, on the openSUSE Leap is a different problem. Firstly almost all real folders are the first one, so I assumed that find doesn't look further. 
Secondly on the server the path in soft links doesn't look like:

```
/projekte/*/3140/software/software.git/
```

but:

```
/projects/*/3140/software/software.git/
```

This is unreadable for all system programs (not only for "find").

The conclusion is this:

- Tumbleweed does not show whether the folder is a soft-link or a
  folder
- Leap is not able to correctly interpret the soft link

And I still don't know how to combine this two things working together.

Comment: I would have expected both versions of GNU `find` to behave as in the second example that you show (returning multiple matches) as you give `find` multiple search paths. If the old version of GNU `find` did not do this, then it was a fault in that program.

Comment: Also, could you pleas clarify whether all you want is the directories that match the particular pattern that you have (you don't need `find` for this), or whether the actual command is more complex.

Comment: I want find the directories that match the particular pattern, and integrate it into bash script as an path array. Everything is already working except this bloody search. 

`SORCE_ARRAY=($(find /projekte/*/$AB/software/software.git/ -maxdepth 0 -type d))
`

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks to you, I noticed that the problem is not the find function, but the interpretation of soft links by the systems.

Answer (score 0):

To find all names that matches the pattern `/projekte/*/3140/software/software.git/`, you can do

```
set -- /projekte/*/3140/software/software.git/
```

The names are then available in the positional parameters:

```
for gitdir do
    printf 'Found directory %s\n' "$gitdir"
done
```

or just

```
printf 'Found directory %s\n' "$@"
```

This would print the names of the found directories. If any name is a symbolic link to a directory, then that symbolic link would be traversed.

If you need to assign these to a named array in e.g. `bash`:

```
set -- /projekte/*/3140/software/software.git/
SORCE_ARRAY=( "$@" )
```

or just

```
SORCE_ARRAY=( /projekte/*/3140/software/software.git/ )
```

This is the preferred way of doing this over expanding a command substitution as a command substitution would not preserve whitespace in filenames.

The only issue is if the pattern does not match *anything* in which case the pattern would be left unexpanded. To have a non-matching pattern expand to nothing at all, use `shopt -s nullglob` in the `bash` shell.

Comment: I'm running both on exactly the same set of filenames - it's the mounted server. 
Set function work's exactly the same as find. 
On first machine (OpenSUSE Tumbleweed) work good and find all paths, on 2nd (Leap 15.0), 3ed (Leap 15.1) and 4th (Leap 15.1)  computer there it's only one path result.

Comment: @RTS007 You don't actually use `find` for anything other than verifying that the names that the pattern expands to are names of directories, which they are since you end the pattern with a slash. The only possible issue with my answer is that if no directory matches the pattern, the pattern will remain unexpanded, which you can mitigate through `shopt -s nullglob` in `bash`.

Comment: Ah, so it's a network mounted share? Well that may mean there may well be other issues than a particular version of `find`. There may be caching issues or something else related to the serving of the network share.

Comment: Yes, it's network mounted share. Mounted with `mount`. Sorry that not mentioned before, I didn't expect it can influence.

Comment: @RTS007 I've used NFS extensively before and experienced directories not showing up properly, even with local NFS mounts.

Answer (score -1):

You should use the `head` command by piping your `find`, this way : `find /foo/*/searched_folder/bar -maxdepth 0 -type d | head -n 1`. This will only get you the first result.

Comment: Unfortunately, the head option doesn't work. It can limit the number of results in the latest version, but it does not help in finding all results in the older version.

Comment: This is the exact opposite of what OP wants to do.